# compiler licensing issue in scons

Tags: scons

Am using scons with renesas compiler.

i am able to compile and link my project. But while linking i am getting following message:

"Software license problem:Internal error in licensing or accessing feature UNKNOWN"

even though i have a trial license of Renesas compiler.

I am able to generate executable (.abs file for renesas) for small application even with the above message. when i tried to create executable for a bigger application i am getting following message while linking:

"Software license problem:Internal error in licensing or accessing feature UNKNOWN"
Maximum link size limited to 64KB code+data.

I tried creating executables for the above appliations using SCONS on a machine which has valid Renesas license. Even on this machine i saw the same messages and i am not able to generate .abs file. ( In this machine i am able to create executables without using scons)

can any one help me in overcoming this issue. I don't have clues whether the message i am getting is from SCONS or Renesas tool chain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that your tool chain sets up some environment variables telling the compiler where to find the licence files. scons wipes out your environment, pretty much, and you may not be propagating the information it needs.

Comment: Hi tom.

but same project with same compiler is working fine in windows xp.

Comment: please can you explane me how scons will check for compiler version or license of the compiler.

Comment: scons wont check for the compiler license and it won't check for the compiler version unless you've set up your own tool. And on windows, the compiler very probably looks in the registry for the licence information, rather than using the environment to find it

Comment: Hi
if i executed the commands manually(in command prompt) or by using batch script(which will have commands to execute the project) we are not getting any licensing issue. if we use scons, then only we are getting the problem like above.

That's why we concluded that, scons having some intelligence to check for license. Is it correct. If not why it is executed by the batch script.

Comment: because scons doesn't pass the environment variables unless you take specific action to do so. scons has no knowledge of individual compilers beyond the default ones provided with certain platforms.